# ¿Cómo invertir los valores ubicados en posiciones impares dentro de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi consulta es la siguiente.

Tengo una lista con los valores :
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Y necesito invertir aquellos valores ubicados en posiciones impares para que quede así:
[9,2,7,4,5,6,3,8,1]

Hasta ahora lo que logre es lo siguiente:

```py
#Funcion
def imprimirlista(vec):
    largo= len(vec)
    for i in range(largo):
        print (vec[i], end= " ")
    print()

def listaimparesinvertida(vec,vec2):
    vec2 = vec[::2]
    vec2 = vec2[::-1]
    largo= len(vec2)
    for i in range(largo):
        print (vec2[i], end= " ")
    print()

#programa principal
v = []
v2= []
n= int(input("Ingrese dato: "))
while n != -1:
    v.append(n)
    n= int(input("Ingrese dato: "))
imprimirlista(v)
listaimparesinvertida(v,v2)
```

Lo cual me genera como salida:

```py
Ingrese dato: 1
Ingrese dato: 2
Ingrese dato: 3
Ingrese dato: 4
Ingrese dato: 5
Ingrese dato: 6
Ingrese dato: 7
Ingrese dato: 8
Ingrese dato: 9
Ingrese dato: -1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 7 5 3 1
```

No tengo idea de como lograr modificar mi primer lista sin necesidad de usar una segunda lista. Y en caso de utilizar una segunda lista, ¿como podria agregarle los valores en posiciones pares ya previamente ingresados?.

Comment: Cual es la pregunta? Al menos intentalo... Parece que quieres que te hagamos la tarea.

Comment: Ya te lo modifique pa, simplemente me pareció un poco caótico el código como para subirlo. :)

Comment: Buenisimo, ahora se entiende más. El truco para no usar multiples arreglos es usar un solo arreglo y manipular sus indices, sabiendo cuales son los indices impares solo basta con revertirlos y luego re-asignar los valores. Tendras que manejar un arreglo de datos y alguno que otro arreglo de indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar el operador de bit `~x` el cual devuelve `-x-1`, de esta manera puedes iterar una lista de manera inversa, ejemplo

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(a):
    a[~i]
```

mostrará

> 5 4 3 2 1

sabiendo esto solo falta recorrer la lista e intercambiar los valores, para ello la lista tiene que tener un tamaño impar, por lo cual de ser par se tendrá que eliminar un valor.

```
valor_extra = None
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
# Si la lista tiene tamaño par le quitamos el ultimo pero lo guardaremos
if len(a)%2==0:
    valor_extra = a[-1]
    a = a[:-1]

# Ahora solo debemos recorrer la lista y reasignar valores
# solo se debe recorrer la mitad de la lista
# ya que de recorrerse completamente quedaria igual
# porque volveríamos a sustituir los valores de nuevo
for i in range(len(a)//2):
    if i%2==0:
        a[i], a[~i] = a[~i], a[i]

# Ahora solo queda agregar el valor que le quitamos en caso de ser necesario    
if valor_extra:
    a += [valor_extra]

print(a)
```

salida

> [9, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 1]

Es la forma que se me ocurre haciéndolo con una sola lista,

**EDITADO**

Para no usar `~` solo basta con sustituirlo por `len(a)-i-1`

```
valor_extra = None
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

if len(a)%2==0:
    valor_extra = a[-1]
    a = a[:-1]

for i in range(len(a)//2):
    if i%2==0:
        a[i], a[len(a)-i-1] = a[len(a)-i-1], a[i]

if valor_extra:
    a += [valor_extra]
```

Eso debe darte el mismo resultado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! si bien me sirve como resolución y para entender mejor el lenguaje, no lo podré aplicar ya que todavía no vimos el operador [~] y al utilizarlo me darían por invalido el ejercicio! Saludos

Comment: te la edito sin ese comando

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no es lo principal de tu pregunta, en tu código la función imprimir podrías cambiarla por un simple `print(*v, end=' ')` que haría lo mismo.

La función `listaimparesinvertida()` puedes conseguirla con el modulo `itertools` de la siguiente forma:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def listaimparesinvertida(vec):
    lista1 = vec[1::2]  # Esto sería [2, 4, 6, 8]
    lista2 = vec[::-2]  # Esto sería [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
    print([i for i in chain(*zip_longest(lista1, lista2)) if i is not None])

listaimparesinvertida(v)
```

Esto devolvería `[9, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 1]`

**Aclaración**

`zip_longest` de `itertools` funciona igual que `zip()` solo que en vez de eliminar los sobrantes en listas de diferente tamaño, añade `None`, por lo que en este caso `zip_longest(lista1, lista2)` devuelve `[(9, 2), (7, 4), (5, 6), (3, 8), (1, None)]`. De ahí el `if i is not None`.

**Sin importación de módulos**

Otra manera sin importar `itertools` sería crear una lista con n elementos `None` e ir asignándoselos:

```
def listaimparesinvertida(vec):
    resultado = len(vec) * [None]
    resultado[1::2] = vec[1::2]
    resultado[::2] = vec[::-2]
    print(resultado)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Es una muy buena y sencilla forma de resolver el ejercicio, aunque no lo podre aplicar ya que todavía en clase no vimos la inserción de módulos, pero te agradezco el tiempo en ayudarme a resolverlo! Saludos